# How I make yacc tell me the expected lexem/toke

Tags: c++, yacc

For example for the rule:

```
%token TOKEN
%%
foo: TOKEN;

%%
```

Considering TOKEN is the the lexem token, then when I parse:

`tokken`

it will show `Syntax error expected TOKEN recive tokken` there is a way to change this so it dosen't say the TOKEN name insted the lexem so: `Syntax error expected token recive tokken` ?

Comment: Err, change the name of `TOKEN?` Not a real question.

Comment: I find it out how I post how, and you can see what I ment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some deep research I find it out and is so:

On the declaration of the token:

parser.y:

```
%token TOKEN "token"

%%

foo : TOKEN
```

This make when you write `tokken` insted of `token` the error message shows what find on the string of the tokken declaration (`%token TOKEN "token"`
). I will make a better example:

parser.y:

```
%token TOKEN "token"   
%token PYC   ";"


%%

foo : TOKEN PYC
```

if your program is `token.` Then the error will be `unexpected "." expecting ";"`.Without the ";" on the line  `%token PYC   ";"` then the error will be `unexpected "." expecting PYC` which is more difficult to understand.